# Is there a standard classification for an Almost Integer in base 10?

Tags: number-theory

At what point is a base 10 number considered to be an Almost Integer? To formalize the question...

$b = [a] - a$

What must the absolute value of $b$ be within for $a$ to be an almost integer?

Comment: The definition is subjective, especially since this concept or notion is related to the field of recreational mathematics... For instance, would you consider $2\pi+e\simeq9$ or $\sqrt{2\pi+e}\simeq3$ as almost integers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Wikipedia article and a few other sources, there doesn't seem to be a clear definition of a "almost integer" aside from the fact that it's supposed to be "close" to an integer. I suppose it doesn't make sense to specify a value for $|b|$ since it would just seem too arbitrary. You can specify that some numbers are "more" of an almost integer than others I suppose.

Comment: I understand. I feel they should be ranked by classes, where a class N almost integer has N 9s or 0s after the decimal point. Therefor, as Lucian's comment suggests, $2\pi + e$ would be a class two almost integer, and it's square root would be class 3.